# Generics with params in constructor and call T method

Tags: java, generics, constructor

I have an abstract class and 2 (for now) daughter class.

Main Class :

```
public abstract class Entite<T> {
    public Entite(int ligne, int colonne, Etat etat) {
        ...
    }
/* Some method here*/
}
```

Daughter 1 (daughter 2 are almost equals):

```
public class Cellule extends Entite<Cellule> {
    public Cellule(int ligne, int colonne, Etat etat) {
        super(ligne, colonne, etat);
    }
/** Override some method here */
}
```

Now I want to use generics in other class.

```
public class Grille<T extends Entite<T>> {
    protected final T[][] grille;
    public Grille(int dimension, int nbCellulesInitiales, Class<T> classe) {
        grille = (T[][])Array.newInstance(classe, 1); // It's good ?
        Etat etat = Etat.Morte;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                grille[i][j] = new T(i, j, etat); //How can I create T (Cellule) object ?
            }
        }
```

Java is new for me so I hope I haven't did idiot error ;)

Comment: Daughter classes? First time I've heard that terminology before...

Comment: Also, what is the question? Do you have an error/exception? If so post it. Does it not do what you want it to do? If so post actual and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an instance like that using a type parameter. You can't associate `new` operator with a type parameter, or wildcard parameterized type types. However, since you already have a `Class<T>` parameter in your constructor, you can use it to get the appropriate constructor using [`Class#getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method. And then instantiate the object using [`Constructor#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method passing appropriate argument:

```
Constructor<T> const = classe.getConstructor(int.class, int.class, Etat.class);

for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
    grille[i][j] = const.newInstance(i, j, etat); 
}
```

Comment: I really don't like this. I would have a look at the bigger picture in the code and see if there's a better design. However this answers the question. +1

Comment: @Cruncher I don't know what to say :(

Comment: This is, while backwards because it is reflection, the correct solution. There's absolutely nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, it's nothing that you can do about it. I just feel like code should never get to the point where this is the solution. I realllly don't like reflection.

Comment: Thank you but I have another question.
Should I let this line :
    `grille = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(classe, 1);`
Or can I replace her by another one ?
If I don't put her I get this error :
    _The blank final field grille may not have been initialized_
Further I have to add in **Grille** constructor :
    `throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,     InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,     IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException`

That's right ?
Thank you again ;)

Comment: @Oyabi 1. Yes you have to have that line there. That is how you initialize an array of type parameters. 2). You don't need to add those in throws clause of constructor. Just use a `try-catch` block around the code requiring them.

Answer (score 0):

The more general way is to pass a factory, instead of passing a `Class`.